# Lenovo thinkpad t14s

Tags: windows

Same issue here. I only had this computer for about two weeks. Turned it on today, saws critics battery error and now it won’t power back on with the charger connected. Never dropped this laptop. No water damage.

Comment: Same issue? Same issue as what? This is not a forum and we do not know what you are referencing. Please post an entire self contained clear and complete question here, and if we are able, it will be answered.

Comment: Send it back for repair or replacement under warranty